# postgresql left outer join column doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql

I am newbie in postgres. I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_details ON order_details.orderid= orders.orderid
```

an it get error

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  column order_details.orderid doesn't exist
LINE 2:       LEFT OUTER JOIN order_details ON order_details.orderid...
                                           ^
In statement:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (SELECT * FROM orders
 LEFT OUTER JOIN order_details ON order_details.orderid= orders.orderid) AS sub
```

What am i missing in my query?
Thanks before

Comment: This is as clear as the sun: order_details.orderid doesn't exist. Can you pelase give the DDL of your `order_details` relation if any ?

Comment: Just run `SELECT * FROM order_details` and examine columns of this table, the error message says that there is no column named `orderid` in this table.

Comment: If the columns were named with double quotes then it will be necessary to reference them using double quotes and the same casing, say, `"OrderId"`

Comment: oke thanks,
btw I'm using this dataset [link](http://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/downloads/detail?name=northwind.postgre.sql&can=2&q=)  maybe anyone can help me?

Comment: I just run `SELECT * FROM order_details` and `orderid` column is appeared

Comment: _I'm using this dataset_ That is exactly the case I mentioned: `CREATE TABLE order_details (
    "OrderID" smallint`. So you need to refer to that column as `"OrderID"`

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo Neto it works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres is case sensitive. Your SQL statement must be in the correct case, and if the table name or column name is not lower case then you must enclose it in double quotation marks. (as shown below)

```
  SELECT * FROM orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_details ON order_details."OrderID"= orders.orderid
```

Comment: With psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.7 , you need "OrderID" also for *orders* : `COPY (SELECT * FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN order_details ON order_details."OrderID" = orders."OrderID") TO '/tmp/orders.csv' WITH CSV header;`